# Pycharm generating weird code template for a test, when using Python's pytest framework for testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, pytest

Why is PyCharm generating the following code template, when clicking "Create New Test..:", even though I have `pytest` as my default test runner?

If my function is `create_training_data`, then PyCharm will generate the following code for this:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestCreate_training_data(TestCase):
    def test_create_training_data(self):
    self.fail()
```

Yet `pytest` neither needs the import, nor the subclassing, having

```
class TestCreate_training_data(object):
    def test_create_training_data(self):
    self.fail()
```

would be enough as already the getting started page shows: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm only knows how to create `unittest` tests at the moment. Please vote for the corresponding feature request: [PY-15021](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15021).

Comment: How many votes does a feature request typically need, until it's being considered for implementation?

Comment: It depends on other issues and the problem severity. This one has enough to be considered on the next release planning I believe.